# The emulator always starts instead of the device

Tags: android, android-emulator

How do I get the eclipse/android environment to run or debug my program on the device instead of on the emulator that I have been using for developement? The adb devices shows that I'm connected to the phone, amd "device manager|Install app" copies the apk to the phone, but I can't find where to setup the phone as the default run/debug device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right-click project > Run As > Run Configurations...

Select your application under Android, select the Target tab, and select the Manual option

This will now prompt you to select a target for deployment instead of automatically choosing the most suitable virtual device.